# Fragment's Toolbar transparent over Activity's toolbar

Tags: android, transparency, toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a peculiar situation which I can't seem to figure out, I have a hunch that it involves the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

I have an activity with the following XML Layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout />
        <!-- Two fragments inside ViewPager each containing a RecyclerView -->
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- User Clicks a button and fragment is added to this framelayout -->
    <!-- This fragment overlays on top of the entire Activity layout -->
    <!-- This fragment also contains a recyclerview -->
    <FrameLayout/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

### And the toolbar for this `Activity` looks like this:

[image]

### Then when I open a `Fragment` on top of this `Activity`'s layout this happens:

[image]

This is the XML for the Fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/fragmentToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how I am initializing the `Fragment`'s toolbar:

```
private void initToolBar(View root) {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) root.findViewById(R.id.fragmentToolbar);
    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(mColor);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}
```

### Why is this an issue?

Comment: Why don't you just move the AppBarLayout into your fragment's layout? Why do you have two toolbars? Assuming you're doing the whole one activity, multiple fragment paradigm.

Comment: Because I have a viewpager, and then there is a button on the activity that create another fragment on top of the Activity + ViewPager.

Comment: Got it.. whats the value of mColor? is that an int value or something?

Comment: Yes, that was probably the first thing I did.

Comment: Make sure that color value has been resolved, like getResources().getColor(mColorInt); I can't even begin to describe how many hours I have lost trying to figure that one out.

Comment: hmm maybe you are correct, if so I feel extremely stupid for not checking the value of mColor

Comment: Yes that was it!!! Arggghgh so many hours wasted :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As hitch.united pointed out it was as simple as checking the value of `mColor`. So many hours wasted! Hope this helps someone else out, if they are ever in the same position!

Comment: this does not answer this could be a comment to the above question.